# how do you put a number '5' and a number '4' to make the number '54'?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

Hi i have been looking all over for an answer but i cannot find one. Basically i am making a currency converter in Tkinter. I have chosen for a display similar to a calculator but i need to be able to use each button and end up with one number. Here's my code(It is not finished yet!):

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Currency Converter")

Currency = []

currency = {"Pound": 1.0,
            "Euro": 1.10,
            "Dollar":1.10}

for i in currency:
    Currency.append(i)

button_list = [
'1', '2', '3',
'4', '5', '6',
'7', '8', '9',
'0', '.']

r = 1
c = 0
for t in button_list:
    cmd = lambda x=t: display.insert(INSERT, x)
    Button(root,text=t,width=3, command=cmd).grid(row=r,column=c, padx=3, pady=3)
    c += 1
    if c > 2:
        c = 0
        r += 1

variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set(Currency[0])

variable2 = StringVar(root)
variable2.set(Currency[0])

startCurrency = apply(OptionMenu, (root, variable) + tuple(Currency))
startCurrency.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2)

label = Label(root, text="To")
label.grid(row=1, column=3)

newCurrency = apply(OptionMenu, (root, variable2) + tuple(Currency))
newCurrency.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)

go = Button(root, text="Go")
go.grid(row=4, column=2)

display = Text(root, width=15, height=1)
display.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time the user clicks a button, you multiply the previous total by ten and add the new number, e.g.:

1. Start with 0
2. <kbd>5</kbd> ==> 0*10 + 5
3. <kbd>4</kbd> ==> 5*10 + 4 = 54
4. <kbd>7</kbd> ==> 54*10 + 7 = 547

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert integers 4 and 5 to strings.
2. Append string 4 to string 5.
3. Convert string 54 to integer 54.

Comment: Obviously this isn't the most processor-efficient way but it's less prone to coding errors than mathy solutions. Since you're essentially making a software copy of a physical calulator and they only do one calculation at a time, users won't notice any lag.

Answer (score 0):

it depends, if you want to make 54 a string, then do

```
"5"+"4"
```

which would make 54,but i'm not too sure how to do the actual number, i used to know but i kinda forgot, sorry